# Estimating Hadoop Scalability Performance on pseudo-distributed nodes?

Tags: performance, hadoop, scalability

Are there any tools, packages, or methodologies available to estimate / simulate the scalability performance of Hadoop using only a single machine using a pseudo-distributed architecture? Such a system would need to make accurate estimations based on jobs that do not interfere with each other in the simulation (e.g., with blocked I/O).

In my mind, how this would work is that I'd run all my map / reduce jobs sequentially, and use some metric to estimate how well the system is scaling (e.g., take the longest running map job and estimate that the run time will be bottlenecked by it).

Additionally, I have multiple map/reduce jobs which are being chained together to form the output.

Comment: Scalability and a single machine. Find the error.

Comment: Not sure if you just read the title or if I wasn't explicit enough... to clarify, I'm not actually expecting it to run faster (sounds absurd!), just to experiment with how well the problem has been broken into subproblems via simulation or estimation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is largely depends on the nature of your job. Let us try to take a few examples:
1. Your job has heavy input formatting and mapper processing, with minimal data passed to reducer. In this case I would estimate that pseudo distributed cluster will realistically reflect real cluster performance (per slot) and you can assume that 5 nodes cluster will have about x5 performance. I would suggest to put enough data that job time will take at least 5-10 times of the job start-up time. This estimation will be better if you have enough splits to ensure data locality during processing. 
If you plan to have a lot of relatively small files - put enough in your test, to simulate per task overhead.
2. Your heavily relaying on Hadoop distributed sort capability (shuffling). Its performance in one node and real cluster can be quite different and the factor is hard to estimate.

I can summarize that throughput of mapper and, in some extent, reducer in terms of MB/sec per slot you can estimated from above. Real cluster probably will have not better performance per slot.